# The problem that the real device using the ECC encryption library CryptoppECC of the secp256k1 curve cannot run normally on the iOS device

Tags: ios, secp256k1

```
 in /Users/ios/Desktop/demo/PodECC/Pods/CryptoppECC/CryptoppECC/CryptoppLibrary/bin/ios/libcryptopp.a(hex.o), building for iOS, but linking in object file (/Users/ios/Desktop/demo/PodECC/Pods/CryptoppECC/CryptoppECC/CryptoppLibrary/bin/ios/libcryptopp.a(hex.o)) built for iOS Simulator, for architecture arm64
```

error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)